# MySQL stored procedure: OUT parameter not being set

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've got a stored procedure in MySQL that gets the next unique ID from a table, to use as an ID for 2 other tables (not the best way to do it, I'm sure, but I'm modifying someone else's code here).  The procedure is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetNextID`( OUT id bigint )
BEGIN
  DECLARE uid VARCHAR(255);
  SET uid = uuid();
  INSERT INTO `ident_column_generator` (u) VALUES (uid);
  SELECT ID INTO id FROM `ident_column_generator` WHERE u = uid;
  DELETE FROM `ident_column_generator` WHERE u = uid;
END$$
```

When I call the procedure from MySQL Workbench:

```
CALL GetNextID( @id );
SELECT @id;
```

@id is `NULL`.  I can't work out what's going wrong?  Even if I run `SET @id = 0;` before calling the procedure, it ends up as NULL afterwards.  If I call the functions within the procedure manually from MySQL Workbench, `@id` outputs fine, e.g.:

```
SET @uid = uuid();
INSERT INTO `ident_column_generator` (u) VALUES (@uid);
SELECT ID INTO @id FROM `ident_column_generator` WHERE u = @uid;
DELETE FROM `ident_column_generator` WHERE u = @uid;
SELECT @id;
```

This outputs @id as being a valid number.

Any ideas why `id` isn't being set properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, spent 3 hours on this, then JUST after I posted the question I find the problem.  So, for future reference:  It appears MySQL is case insensitive where variables are concerned.  The `ID` column name and `id` variable apparently completely confused it.

I changed the procedure's input parameter name to `retId` and then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nick, I also had same issue. The column name and variable name were same due to which we were getting the issue.