# MySQL stored procedure returns wrong values

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Im new to MySQL stored procedures and I was following some tutorial on how to use them, but I ran into an interesting thing with the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `CalculateScores`(IN ID INT, OUT test INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO test
    FROM myTable
    WHERE id = ID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I run it with this:

```
CALL CalculateScores(252, @test);
```

and then just:

```
SELECT @test;
```

The strange thing is that `@test` returns the total row count of the entire table not just for the `id` I sent as a parameter.

What am I missing here? The tutorial never mention this, and I can't find an answer to why this is happening, I might suck at searching..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17673866/1292641

Comment: lol that solved it, thanks for pointing me in the right direction =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like MySQL cannot differentiate between `id` and `ID`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO test
FROM myTable
WHERE id = ID;
```

And it treats it like `1` = `1` which is always true (if column is not nullable).

---

You could add alias to indicate that `id` is column and not parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CalculateScores`(IN ID INT, OUT test INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO test
    FROM myTable t
    WHERE t.id = ID;
END
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=007cc80094dbc96bb0d8df45bde0897b)**

Comment: Wow! This helped! I have a hard time believing some of the things that were designed into MYSQL. They should have made a way for the database compiler to tell the difference between the parameter and a field. This kind of problem doesn't exist in SQL Server and probably not in Oracle either.